# Prevent ng-include switching views

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to avoid using ui-router here. I have a part of my app which needs to swap out a couple of views by using ng-include. In each view will be a directive, and what I'm trying to achieve is having the ability for the inner directives to detect when its about to be swapped out, and to prompt the user before continuing. Similar to how you would capture $stateChangeStart events if you were using ui-router. I can listen to a $destory event within my directive, but there seems to be no way for me to do a 'preventDefault' equivalent:

```
    scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
      console.log('Caught destroy event');
      // Prevent default?
    });
```

[Plunkr here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/J12vOXKiiHHuUK6K3I1q?p=preview) Does anyone know of a way of doing this without switching to using ui-router?

Comment: Similar to `$stateChangeStart` but not using `ui-router`? You mean like `$locationChangeStart`?

Comment: @naeramarth7I'm not changing location though, just swapping out some html with ng-include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I know you cannot use event.preventDefault() on the $destroy event. You could add a different model to your select and use ng-change to show an alert. If the user clicks on OK, you can leave, otherwise just return.

For example:

```
  <select ng-model="selectedTemplate" ng-options="t.name for t in templates" ng-change="onTemplateChange(selectedTemplate)">
```

and

```
$scope.template = $scope.templates[0];
$scope.selectedTemplate = $scope.template

$scope.onTemplateChange = function(template) {
    // show an alert and on success change the template
    // TODO: implement alert
    // if OK, change the template
    $scope.template = template; 
    }
```

[see Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/QqDuIzvk2Lljc3s7xUrS?p=preview)

Comment: Yeah this would work, however, I was hoping to do it within the directive in the template as they would know if it was appropriate to pop up an alert (for example, if the user had made changes). I think you are right though, that there is no way to do it natively :(